# Prove that: For every group there exists a faithful representation over any nontrivial commutative ring.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I know the approach of the proof is like:
Every group is isomorphic to a permutation group.Let R be a nontrivial commutative ring and A be a set. Then the set M of all functions A to R is an R-module. If S(A) is the group of all permutations of A, then there exists an injective group homomorphism S(A) to AutR(M).
But how can I define this injective group (with details, please).
Thanks

Comment: Representation in question is not assumed to be finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

The injective homomorphism (not injective group --- that was presumably a typo in the question) that you want sends each permutation $p$ of $A$ to the automorphism $\bar p$ of the module $M$ defined as follows.  For any element $x\in M$, $x$ is (as you said) a function from $A$ into $R$.  So you can compose it with permutations of $A$.  The obvious thing to try is to set $\bar p(x)=x\circ p$, but I think you'll get better results if you define $\bar p(x)=x\circ(p^{-1})$.  ("Better results" means that it works with the standard "right before left" order of composition.)